# install gensim error in ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, gensim

I trying to install gensim using the following command:

```
sudo pip install gensim
```

I got the following error messages:

```
The directory '/home/woojung/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is
not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please  
check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with 
sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.


The directory '/home/woojung/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not 
owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the   
permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you  
may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting gensim
Downloading gensim-2.3.0.tar.gz (17.2MB)
99% |████████████████████████████████| 17.2MB 422kB/s eta  
0:00:01Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/woojung/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages 
/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
status = self.run(options, args)
File "/home/woojung/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands 
/install.py", line 324, in run
requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)

....


File "/home/woojung/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor
/cachecontrol/filewrapper.py", line 50, in _close
self.__callback(self.__buf.getvalue())
File "/home/woojung/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor
/cachecontrol/controller.py", line 275, in cache_response
self.serializer.dumps(request, response, body=body),
File "/home/woojung/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor
/cachecontrol/serialize.py", line 87, in dumps
).encode("utf8"),
MemoryError
```

I installed numpy and scipy. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: It's considered bad practice to install packages as `sudo`. Can you just run  `pip install gensim`?

Comment: Thank you. But, same result...

Answer (score 1):

No need for sudo, and try

```
pip --no-cache-dir install gensim
```

You're getting a `MemoryError` from pip, so it's not really gensim's problem. You can search for similar solutions